# how to solve org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am currently writing a program where i am trying to read a password protected excel file. I am acheveing this using Apache POI library. Below is my code being 
used for reading the file.

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(recordFile), "password");
```

However, i am getting org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files exception. I have downloaded the zip file from oracle website and have installed two jars under %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security folder. I am still getting the error

Any idea how this error could be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract jars here :%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security

Comment: i have extracted the jars at the following location - %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security stil i am getting the error.

Comment: try this : `System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"));` does that return "2147483647" or "128" ?

Comment: System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")); returns "128"

Comment: Ok, so JCE jars are not installed in your jvm. Do you run your code from IDE (eclipse, intellij, ... ) ? I suspect you don't use the right jdk (the one where you install jars from oracle)

Comment: yeah, i am running the code using IDE - eclipse. So i have jdk1.7.0_80 installed on my machine and i have extracted the jars (local_policy and US_export_policy) at the same location where my jdk is installed

Comment: Check here, if eclipse use the right jdk : Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's 

I recommend you to delete other jdk

Comment: i checked the jdk at installed JRE`s location - it is pointing to the jdk1.7.0_80 and it is the only jdk installed

Comment: i also ran a simple program keeping the java source file under bin location to ensure it isnot the issye with IDE, System.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")); i still received 128 as the output

Comment: i was able to get pass through this error, now i am able to get 2147483647 by running the following statementSystem.out.println(Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES")) i re-installed the jdk and replaced the local_policy and US_export_policy jars at following location - %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security Thanks @Quentin Geff for the pointers